# Noise in KRK's when using Audio interface

Tags: noise, audio-interfaces, studio-monitors

I bought an audio interface and connected it to my laptop. I use a display via HDMI. But when I connect my laptop with the audio interface to the display a weird cracking noise is coming out of the KRK's. 
The audio interface is working fine when I do not connect my laptop to the display via HDMI. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could start by specifying the actual gear that is involved (no, mentioning the brand name of the speakers isn't enough) as well as which connections you are using between which connectors on which piece of gear.

Comment: I use the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 and an Acer K242HYL as a display. The speakers are KRK Rokit 5 and are connected via RCA and 6.3mm jacks go into the audio interface. These are all the connections I use

Comment: I feel like the audio which goes through the HDMI is conflicting with the audio which goes through the usb from the audio interface. Because i get the same exact noise when I connect the krk's via 3.5mm to my laptop and usb audio interface at the same time and i don't use the HDMI display then. If this makes any sense lol

Comment: This information should be edited into your question, rather than added as a comment [on an answer which should also have been a comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the comments you added to your original posting: you are using powered speakers that have balanced TRS inputs, an audio interface that has balanced TRS outputs, and you connect them with unbalanced TS-to-RCA cables?

The powered speakers, for better or worse, will have some relation to the ground at least via some capacitance, and they have separate power supplies.  That means that you have a ground loop that is susceptible to magnetic interference.  It's the same with 3.5mm unbalanced jacks.

So connect your speakers with balanced TRS cables to your soundcard: that gives you a much better chance at taking "ground out of the loop", likely also mitigating your HDMI interference problem.